# SelectBox not updating data while editing in angularjs using php

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I am getting my data using json array via php now on edit operation when I got the data in select box on changing different values data is not updating .Any help would be appreciated.

```js
$scope.rec = []; 
$scope.update = function(rec){     
  var id = $scope.id;   
  $scope.upload = $upload.upload({
    //url: 'api/manage_features/update/'+id, //upload.php script, node.js route, or servlet url 
    url: 'api/AdminArea/users/update/'+id,
    method: 'POST', 
    headers: {'header-key': '83c238df1650bccb2d1aa4495723c63f07672ee8'}, 
    withCredentials: true, 
    data:rec , //{data:rec},
    //data: {name:$scope.name,price:$scope.price},

  }).progress(function(evt) {
    console.log('percent: ' + parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
  }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    toaster.pop('success', 'Edit', 'Record Updated successfully.');
    setTimeout(function(){ $state.go('app.manage_users'); }, 3000);
    $scope.$root.$broadcast("myDocEventReload", {});
  })
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Role:</label>
  <div class="col-lg-5">
    <div ng-show="addForm.$submitted || addForm.Name.$touched">
      <div ng-show="addForm.Name.$error.required" style="color:red;">Field required!.</div>
    </div>

    <select class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="rec.roles" name="Role">
      <option ng-repeat="roles in user " ng-selected="{{rec.roles==user.Role}}" value="{{roles.Role}}"  >{{roles.Role}}</option>
    </select>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Post your whole JS code (including Angular initialization) on JSBin or JsFiddle and give us the link. I suspect that something is wrong when you bootstrap Angular.

Comment: You need to add `$scope.apply()` after `$scope.$root.$broadcast("myDocEventReload", {});` Read about this here: http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html